# Laravel PHP Get a check box value saving to a tiny int

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I have a form in a blade view that saves until I include the checkboxes.
Form check box:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-4">
   {{Form::label('o3', 'Option 3')}}
   {{Form::checkbox('o3','',false,['class' => 'form-control med-width'])}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```php
$vote->choice3 = $request->input('o3');
```

I should comment that I have 3 checkboxes o1-o3 all showing the same all with the same formatting.

I get the Error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'choice3' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'votes' ('student_number', 'surname', 'campus', 'choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (955555, Test, Singleton Campus, ?, ?, ?, 2019-10-30 15:35:13, 2019-10-30 15:35:13))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox inputs are not sent if they are not checked, which leads to their value being `null` when you recover them in your controller. You should set a default value for them using `input()`'s second parameter

```php
$choice1 = $request->input('o1', 0);
$choice2 = $request->input('o2', 0);
$choice3 = $request->input('o3', 0);
```

The second parameter in the method `input()` represents the default value if the input is not sent by the browser.

Or make your `choice1`, `choice2` and `choice3` fields nullable in your DB.